# FileNotFoundError: Caught FileNotFoundError in DataLoader worker process 1

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am training an AI model in Google colab. My dataset is on my google drive and I mount my google drive to my notebook,  But every few hours I get the same error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-36d279d25314> in <cell line: 8>()
      8 for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
      9     train_loader = train_loaders[epoch % len(train_loaders)]
---> 10     generator_loss, discriminator_loss = train_fn(discriminator_model, generator_model, train_loader, discriminator_optimizer, generator_optimizer,DEVICE, L1_LOSS, BCE, g_scaler, d_scaler, save_interval)
     11 
     12     generator_training_losses.append(generator_loss)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py in reraise(self)
    642             # instantiate since we don't know how to
    643             raise RuntimeError(msg) from None
--> 644         raise exception
    645 
    646 

FileNotFoundError: Caught FileNotFoundError in DataLoader worker process 1.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 308, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Python_Libraries/flexingtosketchesdataset.py", line 156, in __getitem__
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Python_Libraries/reuseablecustompythonfunctions.py", line 178, in process_images_with_normalization
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Python_Libraries/reuseablecustompythonfunctions.py", line 157, in rotate_image_based_on_exif
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2975, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/artist_flex_sketch/MedianBlur_Photos/187.png'
```

The image it cant find is always different.

I am not sure if it would be helpful or not for me to post my full dataset notebook. but here is my Dataset class code:

```
from sys import path
path.append("/content/drive/MyDrive/Python_Libraries")
import reuseablecustompythonfunctions as rcpf

class Pix2PixDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_points,transforms=None):
        self.transforms = transforms
        self.resize = T.Resize((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH))
        self.data_points = data_points 
       
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        real_image, sketch = rcpf.process_images_with_normalization(self.data_points[index].reference_image, self.data_points[index].drawing)
        
        if apply_random_transformation:
            real_image, sketch = random_transformation(real_image, sketch)
        
        real_image = self.resize(real_image)
        sketch = self.resize(sketch)

        if self.transforms:
            real_image = self.transforms(real_image)
            sketch = self.transforms(sketch)
        return (real_image, sketch)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_points)
```

I have a python file for reusable functions and that is where my process images with normalization function is at:

```
def process_images_with_normalization(reference_image_path, drawing_path):
    # Open the images
    reference_image = rotate_image_based_on_exif(reference_image_path).convert("RGB")
    drawing = rotate_image_based_on_exif(drawing_path).convert("RGB")
    
    # Convert images to numpy arrays
    reference_image_np = np.array(reference_image)
    drawing_np = np.array(drawing)
   
    # Normalize the image data to 0-1
    reference_image_np = reference_image_np.astype('float32') / 255.0
    drawing_np = drawing_np.astype('float32') / 255.0
    
    # Convert numpy arrays back to PIL Images
    reference_image = PIL.Image.fromarray((reference_image_np * 255).astype(np.uint8))
    drawing = PIL.Image.fromarray((drawing_np * 255).astype(np.uint8))

    return reference_image, drawing
```

Some of the images in my dataset was taking at an angle,  so I could get the full body into the picture, so I had to add this to my code:

```
def rotate_image_based_on_exif(image_path):
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    try:
        for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys() :
            if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation] == 'Orientation':
                break

        exif = dict(image._getexif().items())

        if exif[orientation] == 3 :
            image=image.rotate(180, expand=True)
        elif exif[orientation] == 6 :
            image=image.rotate(270, expand=True)
        elif exif[orientation] == 8 :
            image=image.rotate(90, expand=True)
    except (AttributeError, KeyError, IndexError):
        # In case of issues with EXIF data of the image
        pass
    return image
```

Anyhow, I am not sure if that is helpful or not, because the code run for over 185 epochs before it could not find that image during  the 186 epoch.

Here are my colab Notebook settings:
My Runtime type is Python 3.
My Hardware accelerator is GPU.
My GPU Type is A100.
And My Runtime shape is High-RAM.

Again, I am not sure if that is useful or not.

Also, My dataset is in another python file that I load on my training file.

```
DEVICE = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

I tried preloading all my images in RAM, but there was too many and colab kept crashing.

Comment: I would suggest to verify the dir first "/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/artist_flex_sketch/MedianBlur_Photos/" 
try checking isdir() for this path first 
That will help you and no need to share the rest of the code - I don't think it has any dependency on other code ( just in case it is resolving consider dataset class path.append() line to debug further)